# NULL inserted instead of default column value

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table in my MySQL database that contains a column `status` with a default value, defined in database side using phpMyAdmin. When I insert a new row using Hibernate, I get this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'status' cannot be null

Do I need to do anything more to use the default value?

**Entity**

```
@Entity
class Purchase {

    //More fields
    private String status;

    @Basic
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should set `status` a default value in entity, or you can use sql to insert record without fileld  `status`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use default value for the field

```
private String status = "Default";
```

or use @PrePersist Annotion,

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    if(status == null)
        status = "Default value";
}
```